# how to declare a non linear objective function in pyomo? and efficient way of declaring constraints?

Tags: python, constraints, nonlinear-optimization, pyomo

I am trying to declare a non linear objective constraint in Pyomo and everytime I try to solve it using Bonmin Solver, I get the following error:

ERROR: Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (3221225477)
ERROR: Solver log: Bonmin 1.8.6 using Cbc 2.9.9 and Ipopt 3.12.8 bonmin:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 2, in 
    results = opt.solve(model)

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 626, in solve
    "Solver (%s) did not exit normally" % self.name)

ApplicationError: Solver (asl) did not exit normally

#

My Objective function definition is:

```
`def obj_func(model):
   global summer
   summer = 0
   global volumer
   volumer = 0
   for i in range(0,len(data)):
        summer += model.x[i]*data.loc[i,'Predicted.Profit']
   for j in range(0,len(data)):
        volumer += model.x[j]*data.loc[j,'Predicted.Liters.Sold']
   return summer/volumer`
```

I am invoking the solver through SolverFactory,
Lastly I would also like to know the most efficient way of creating constraints as i have constraints of the range 100+ and some of them are non linear. When i try to solve the problem using this model, my memory usage spikes to 100% and my computer hangs.

Comment: Look for the logs. They are written to some place. But it sounds just like a memory error and then it's hard to recommend someting different than solving a smaller model or buy ram. It looks like a ML task where general nlp solvers often do not scale.

Comment: What do you mean by "It looks like a ML task where general nlp solvers often do not scale"?

Comment: Are you doing machine learning with big data? Then dont expect to be able to use general nonlinear opt

Comment: No, I have dataset with size (178848,40). I am able to run CBC very easily but it is failing with BONMIN or COUENNE

Comment: That's pretty big and you should not compare linear opt with nonlinear opt.

Comment: Is there something I can do to optimize the non linear optimization?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the solver output to see why it's failing. You can print this output to the screen by adding the `tee=True` option when calling the solver:

```
SolverFactory('bonmin').solve(model, tee=True)
```

Also, when declaring Pyomo Constraints and Objectives, you should avoid using `+=`. It can often lead to significant performance degradation when building Pyomo expressions. Here is the recommended way to write your objective function:

```
def obj_func(model):
   return sum(model.x[i]*data.loc[i,'Predicted.Profit'] for i in model.I)/sum(model.x[j]*data.loc[j,'Predicted.Liters.Sold'] for j in model.J)
model.Objective(rule=_obj_func)
```

where `model.I` and `model.J` are either Pyomo `Set` components or Python lists.